# Checking if a value is in an array and then using that value

Tags: c#

I have a method which recieves an array of strings from another method.
This array contains several strings, for days, moviegenres etc.
I need to check if the array contains any of the moviegenres, and if so I need that specific value.

here is what I have now:

```
if (eventsSelected.Contains("act") ||
               eventsSelected.Contains("adv") ||
               eventsSelected.Contains("ani") ||
               eventsSelected.Contains("doc") ||
               eventsSelected.Contains("dra") ||
               eventsSelected.Contains("hor") ||
               eventsSelected.Contains("mys") ||
               eventsSelected.Contains("rom") ||
               eventsSelected.Contains("sci") ||
               eventsSelected.Contains("thr"))
            {
                //get the value that is in the array contains.
            }
```

Because my code checks for 10 different values how can I find out which value is true?

So let's say the array contains the value "act" how can I get that specific value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
foreach(var match in new [] {"act", "adv"}.Where(eventsSelected.Contains))
{
    //do stuff
}
```

Or if you just need the first one

```
var match = Array.Find(new[] { "act", "adv" }, eventsSelected.Contains);
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(match))
{
    // If you just want the first match
}
```

The `match` field contains the token you were searching on, so `act` or `adv`.

Answer (score 3):

Either use multiple `if` or use a `string[]` and [`Array.FindIndex`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/03y7c6xy(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
string[] tokens = {"adv", "ani", "doc" .... };
int index = Array.FindIndex(tokens, t => eventsSelected.Contains(t));
if(index >= 0)
{
     Console.WriteLine("First value found was: " + tokens[index])
}
```

Comment: If you wanna use the static Array methods, you can use the `Array.Find`, since the `index` value is never really used.

Comment: @YuriyFaktorovich: well, it has one advantage, you can use [`Array.FindIndex(array, startIndex, predicate)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhdxx3we(v=vs.110).aspx) if you want to find the next  match. You just need to pass `++index`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Intersect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
var values = new[] {"act", "adv", "ani", etc};
var matches = values.Intersect(eventsSelected);

//matches contains all matching values
```

Comment: This does an equality comparison, not a `Contains` like OP does.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Actually, I'm not sure it does. If eventsSelected is an array (and the name suggests it is), then Contains is testing equality for each element of the array.

Comment: Agreed. Code is ambiguous.

Comment: eventsSelected is indeed an array, I realise I should have made that more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the answer from Tim, but using LINQ rather than Array functions:

```
string[] tokens = {"adv", "ani", "doc" .... };
string firstMatch = eventsSelected.FirstOrDefault(s => tokens.Contains(s));
if (firstMatch != null)
{
    // Do something with firstMatch
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't help but notice that you've written your tokens in sorted order so just for the fun of it you could do:

```
string[] sortedTokens = {"act", "adv", "ani", ... };
int index = Array.FindIndex(eventsSelected, e => Array.BinSearch(sortedTokens, e) > 0)
```

And then proceed as in Tim's answer, except that this time, `index` is the index from `eventsSelected`. This gives you O(nlog(k)) time complexity, where `n` is the size of eventsSelected and `k` is the size of tokens (other answers give O(nk), not that it matters much).